# Como passar o código (id) pela minha viwer usando o thymeleaf e spring mvc para a controller?

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web, spring-mvc, xampp

Minha entidade:

```
package local.demo.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Evento implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long codigo;
private String nome;
private String local;
private String data;
private String horario;

//gets e sets

}
```

Minha Controller:

```
package local.demo.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import local.demo.models.Evento;
import local.demo.repository.EventoRepository;

@Controller
public class EventoController {

@Autowired
private EventoRepository er;

@RequestMapping(value = "/cadastrarEvento", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String form() {
    return "evento/formEvento";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/cadastrarEvento", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(Evento evento) {
    er.save(evento);
    return "redirect:/cadastrarEvento";
}

@RequestMapping("/eventos")
public ModelAndView listaEventos() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");       
    Iterable<Evento> eventos = er.findAll();
    mav.addObject("eventos", eventos);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping("/{codigo}")
public ModelAndView detalhesEvento(@PathVariable("codigo") long codigo) {
    Evento evento = er.findByCodigo(codigo);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("evento/detalhesEvento");
    mv.addObject("evento", evento);     
    return mv;
}
}
```

Meu repositorio (interface):

```
package local.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import local.demo.models.Evento;

public interface EventoRepository extends CrudRepository<Evento, String> {
Evento findByCodigo(long codigo);
}
```

Minha viwer (index):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<title>Cria Eventos Facil</title>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--Import materialize.css-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" 
media="screen,projection"/>

<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lista de Eventos</h1>
<h3>
    <a href="/cadastrarEvento">Cadastrar Evento</a>
</h3>
<table class="container">
    <thead>
        <tr>        
            <th>Id</th>  
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Local</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Horario</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="evento : ${eventos}">                      
            <!--<td><a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#detalhesEvento').arg(0, evento.codigo)).build()}"><span th:text="${evento.nome}"></span></a></td>-->
            <td><span th:text="${evento.codigo}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.nome}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.local}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.data}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.horario}"></span></td>              
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bom, é aqui que começa os erros, se deixo o evento.codigo para ser mostrado da esse erro:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 14 10:31:16 BRT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "evento.codigo" (index3:34)

Agora se comento o evento.codigo e descomento a linha que estava comentada no codigo que é o que eu realmente preciso:

```
<tbody>
        <tr th:each="evento : ${eventos}">                      
            <td><a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#detalhesEvento').arg(0, evento.codigo)).build()}"><span th:text="${evento.nome}"></span></a></td>
            <!--<td><span th:text="${evento.codigo}"></span></td>-->
            <td><span th:text="${evento.nome}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.local}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.data}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.horario}"></span></td>              
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Da esse erro aqui:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 14 11:36:04 BRT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(#mvc.url('EC#detalhesEvento').arg(0, evento.codigo)).build()" (index:31)

Uso o XAMPP - MySQL para o bd e meu codigo para config. de bd é esse:

```
package local.demo.data;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DataConfiguration {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demoteste");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
    return adapter;
}
}
```

Bom, agora eu não sei se o erro é relativo ao "id", pois na minha "tbl" o tipo e "bigint" (criado automaticamente) e nas minhas classes conforme os códigos são "long" ou se o erro é em outra coisa. Sei que o ideal é usar uma camada de SERVICE onde eu poço colocar toda a lógica de negócio e tirar essa responsabilidade do "controller", mas prefiro uma ajuda se possível nesse cenário que estou passando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, você poderia remover o comentário onde você mostra o "{evento.id}" e substituir isso `<a th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#detalhesEvento').arg(0, evento.codigo)).build()}">` por isso: `<a th:href="@{/seuContexto{id}(id = ${evento.id}) }"></a>`

Comment: Sim vou tentar, mas ao invés de ser "id" pode ser o codigo, tipo: <a th:href="@{/seuContexto{codigo}(codigo = ${evento.codigo}) }"></a>???

Comment: Pode sim. Coloquei "id" porque geralmente utilizam para referenciar a primary key. Mas, já que você referenciou como "código", não há problemas.

Comment: Erro na console: EL1008E: Property or field 'codigo' cannot be found on object of type 'local.demo.models.Evento' - maybe not public?

Erro na web: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 14 13:47:42 BRT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "evento.codigo" (index:33)

Comment: os getters/setters do código foram criados, certo? Mostre-me a sua view, como ela ficou depois da alteração.

Comment: Ficou assim: 
<tr th:each="evento : ${eventos}">     
            <td><a th:href="@{/detalhesEvento{codigo}(codigo = ${evento.codigo})}"></a></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.nome}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.local}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.data}"></span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${evento.horario}"></span></td>              
        </tr>

Comment: Conserta aí: `<a th:href="@{/detalhesEvento/{codigo}(codigo = ${evento.codigo})}"></a>`

Comment: Mesmo erro! Não sei mais o que fazer, venho copiando o código exatamente igual ao curso que eu estou fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, o erro que você informa

> Erro na console: EL1008E: Property or field 'codigo' cannot be found
>   on object of type 'local.demo.models.Evento' - maybe not public? Erro
>   na web: Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping
>   for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Wed Mar 14 13:47:42
>   BRT 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "evento.codigo"
>   (index:33)

é devido a falta de `getter` e `setter` do campo `codigo` de sua classe evento.

Insira esses `getter` e `setter` que vai funcionar.

Comment: Poxa não é isso Vitor eu conferir isso, valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, amigo, eu consegui resolver este problema alterando de `(@PathVariable("codigo")` para `(@PathVariable("evento.codigo")`

e também alterar o `@RequestMapping("/{codigo}") para @RequestMapping("/{evento.codigo}")`

para exibir o código na url após o clique no evento.

Abs.